# Result into array

Tags: php, sql

I want to put the result of an sqli-query into an array, but I have absolutley no idea how to do that.

In the example code are 2 results, but only one of them ends up in the array.

Can't wait to hear your ideas!

```
$result = runSQL("SELECT `trackingnumber` FROM `tracking` WHERE `chat_id`=$chatId");                
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
               $res = $row['trackingnumber']; 
               $info = array($res); 
            }
        print_r($info);
```

Comment: What do you mean by the second one?

Comment: @executable so runSQL returns 2 trackingnumbers, but in $info is only one of them

Comment: Your query is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Comment: Depending on your API (MySQLi/PDO), there's a `fetchAll()` you can use, so that you don't have to iterate over it, which might be easier.

Comment: @DarkBee Don't know how this should help me with this point :D

Comment: It's just a `FYI` - up to you if read into it or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the variable `info` with each iteration. You need to append your results, e.g.

```php
$info = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $info[] = $row['trackingnumber']; 
}
```